# How to pass data to a PHP file from a list-group item?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm making a simple 3-step form, the first step is choosing between a list of "things", instead of making a boring radio button I choose a bootstrap list-group.
But how I can pass the value chosed from the user to a PHP file?

I will paste the list-group code down here

```html
  <div id="scelta_materia">
    <form method="POST" action="dopo.php">
      <div class="row spazio_scelta">
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Italiano</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Storia</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Geografia</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Matematica</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Scienze</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Fisica</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Inglese</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary spazio_button">Successivo</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form

Comment: I already made a form and tried to "catch" the data by the id after the "POST" check in the PHP file but it doesn't work

Comment: can you show the php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you'll have to use some JavaScript code:

```
$('#list-tab a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');

  // Get user selection
  var userSelection = $(this).text();

  // Check if input does not already exists
  if ($('input[name="my_input"]').length === 0) {
    // Create hidden input
    var input = $('<input type="hidden" name="my_input" />');
    input.val(userSelection)
    // Prepend new input to form
    $('#scelta_materia').find('form').prepend(input);
  } else {
    $('input[name="my_input"]').val(userSelection);
  }
});
```

For example, if user selects `Scienze` list group item, an `<input type="hidden" name="my_input" value="Scienze" />` will be added to the form.

After form submission, you can retreive your input value in PHP with `$_POST['my_input']`

I hope it helps you :)